# How to find k8s namespace delete history

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

A namespace is deleted and all containers in the namespace are lost.
I run command `history | grep delete`, but didn't get any namespace delete history.

Could anyone help find the delete reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled [auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) of all requests to Kubernetes API Server on the kubernetes cluster then you could find out who submitted the delete request to delete the namespace and when.Audting is a recommended best practice to find out this kind of information in a production cluster.